# Obtener el tamaño de pantalla en Python

Tags: python

La pregunta es sencilla. Quiero saber cómo obtener el ancho y el alto de la pantalla en Python.

Y si eso requiere importar en mi programa un módulo especial, agradecería un enlace en el que poder descargarlo, porque en varios casos que busque resulto que no tenia en Python el módulo necesario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si usas Windows puedes valerte de [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) de la biblioteca estándar (no necesitas módulos externos) para ello:

```
import ctypes


user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
user32.SetProcessDPIAware()
ancho, alto = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)
print(ancho, alto)
```

Igualmente, en Linux/Unix con soporte para `X` y `Randr` puedes hacer uso de [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html):

```
import subprocess


def screen_size():
    size = (None, None)
    args = ["xrandr", "-q", "-d", ":0"]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(args,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    for line in proc.stdout:
        if isinstance(line, bytes):
            line = line.decode("utf-8")
            if "Screen" in line:
                size = (int(line.split()[7]),  int(line.split()[9][:-1]))
    return size

size = screen_size()
print(size)
```

Comment: ¡Gracias! Ha funcionado

Answer (score 2):

Si estás con Windows y Python 3.x puedes obtener el nº de pixels con:

```
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics


print("Ancho =", GetSystemMetrics(0))
print("Alto =", GetSystemMetrics(1))
```

Si te da error, posiblemente no tengas instalado ese módulo. Puedes instarlo ejecutando el siguiente comando en una ventana nueva:

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

Tienes más información [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129322/how-do-i-get-monitor-resolution-in-python). Por ejemplo, para una solución que funcione tanto en Windows, Mac o Linux (multiplataforma) y con varios monitores, puestos a instalar paquetes tienes `screeninfo`.

Para instalarlo, abres una ventana de comandos nueva y escribes:

```
pip install screeninfo
```

Para obtener la información de los monitores, inicias sesión de Python y escribes:

```
from screeninfo import get_monitors
for m in get_monitors():
    print(str(m))
```

Tienes el código en [GitHub](https://github.com/rr-/screeninfo) por si quieres darle un vistazo.

Comment: Me sale este mensaje de error: ImportError: No module named 'win32api'. ¿Deberia encontrarse el modulo en "\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages"? Por cierto, uso la version 64, no la 32

Comment: Vaya, parece que no lo tienes instalado. Prueba a instalar el paquete antes con: `pip install pypiwin32`. He actualizado la respuesta. Mira a ver te sigue dando problemas.

Comment: Hay otro problema. Tuve que reinstalar python, y ahora no se reconoce el comando pip. "pip no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable".